# How to UPDATE record in two different tables using PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a page called update.php and what i want to do is that i want to update a record a record in two tables at the same time.what i have here now is just updating in a single table, can anyone please help me with it?

****here is my code for class.user.php**

```
public function update($user_id,$username,$password,$province)
{
try
{
  $stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE login SET  username=:username,password=:password,province=:province WHERE user_id=:user_id");
  $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
  $stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
  $stmt->bindparam(":province",$province);
  $stmt->execute();

  return true;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
  return false;
}
}
```

**and here is now for update.php**

```
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-update']))
    {
    $ID = $_GET['ID'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $province = $_POST['province'];

if($crud->update($ID,$username,$password,$province))
    {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Updated!');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updating Failed!'); </script>";
    }
}
    if(isset($_GET['ID']))
    {
    $ID = $_GET['ID'];
    extract($crud->getID($ID)); 
}
?>
```

Comment: You would perform two update statements (ie have two execute calls), but wrap it in a transaction. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php

Comment: @Scuzzy but how can i do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what the hurdle in your understanding here is. To update two tables, do the same thing you do with one table, but do it twice. If you want to put it in a transaction,  see the doc Scuzzy just linked to.

Comment: So i need to do it same as i do in the first.but can i do that theres no connection between the two tables?

Comment: Why does there need to be a connection? `UPDATE foo SET a=1; UPDATE bar SET x='hello';` is perfectly OK SQL.

Comment: @locallocal Are your tables in the same database or different database? Does the same login credentials access both tables?

Comment: i need to do 2 queries right?

Comment: Not necessarily no. But we do need to understand more about the table/database structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
  UPDATE login, login2
    SET login.username =            :username, 
        login.password =           :password,
        login.province =        :province, 
         login2.username =            :username, 
        login2.contacts =           :contacts            
    WHERE login.user_id = :user_id and login2.user_id = :user_id ;
```

Comment: do i need set a foreign for it?

Comment: the two table have any connection?

Comment: no..there's no connection between them.how can i update those two tables without any connection between them..

Comment: two tables have same fileds?

Comment: post your table fields

Comment: table A consist of user_id,username,password,province  and in table B consist of id,username,contacts the table A and B has same field of username

Comment: i already tried your code but there an error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'Province' in field list is ambiguous